# Plot 2D plane in 3D graph with Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, graph, 3d, plotly, plotly.js

I am using plotly.js to plot my graph and Ive come to a problem. I am trying to plot a 2D plane in 3D graph. For example i have equation x >= 5 so the plane should be perpendicular to the x axis, i can calculate the 4 corner x,y,z coordinates easily. But dont know how to plot It using either mesh3d or surface3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think this is a bug ([just posted it here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3389)). Meanwhile, a workaround is to specify the vertex vectors:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Mesh3d(x=[0,1,1,0],
                        y=[1,1,1,1],
                        z=[0,0,1,1],
                        opacity=0.2,
                        color='black',
                        i=[0, 0, 0, 1],
                        j=[1, 2, 3, 2],
                        k=[2, 3, 1, 3],
                  ))
fig.show()
```